# Convert hair particles to mesh, while keeping them deformed by armature

Tags: mesh, armature, hair, conversion

I use a new workflow to map some fur on my characters using vertex weights, i wonder how i could convert the hair (or fur here) particles to mesh, while keeping them deformed by the armature i use with my character?

Or if you know any other way to export the mesh with the hairs as mesh, and deformed by the rig?[image: On top, the hairs are not yet converted, they fit the deformation of the armature, on bottom, hairs are converted, they don't follow armature anymore.]

On top, the hairs are not yet converted, they fit the deformation of the armature, on bottom, hairs are converted, they don't follow armature anymore.

I want the hairs to keep being deformed by the armature, like on top picture, even after the "Convert" button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The new mesh needs to parented to the Armature. After you have pushed the 'convert' button - select your new mesh in *Object Mode* and shift select your armature. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Armature...

...select your bones in Pose Mode. Select your new 'hair' mesh and enter *Weight Paint* mode. You should see your bones are selected here too. Under weights click Assign automatic from bones. If need be, weight paint to adjust the effect.

Comment: No that's not what i ask for, i know how to parent a mesh to an armature, but the converted hairs have even lost the vertex weights and vertex group from the past mesh, so it gives bad results. 

I want to know if it's possible to convert  while keeping the hairs affected by the armature like they already were.

Comment: Maybe add some images or examples of what you are trying to achieve? I very clearly have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: Updated the answer to include another step. Should work now...

Comment: Well, my bad, the hairs have no weights before we convert them, it was an illusion cause it takes a position relative to faces on the mesh.

So ok i suppose i have to make the weights myself.

Btw, your operation is not really possible since there is plenty of meshes created when we convert the hairs, not a single one, no?

Comment: Try it and you'll soon see it it's possible. One bone can move every mesh in the universe if you assign and weight it. How good it looks? Well that might take a bit of back & forward. Good luck!

Comment: well i wanted a fast a clever solution somehow, ill try to script something instead i suppose.